# How to import a library bundled with webpack 5 in an html script tag

Tags: javascript, webpack

While trying to migrate from webpack 4 to webpack 5, my library fails to load within an html script tag. I have found many posts discussing how to do it with webpack 4 but none for webpack 5.

My current minimal project is made of :

```
// src/index.js
function test() {
    return 42
}

export {test}
```

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        port: 3030,
    },
    entry: {
        lib: "./src/index.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: `[name].js`,
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        library: "MyLib"
    },
}
```

```
// index.html
<script src="http://localhost:3030/lib.js"></script>

<script>
    try { console.log(MyLib); } catch (error) { console.warn("error MyLib")}
    try { console.log(window.MyLib); } catch (error) { console.warn("error window.MyLib")}
    try { console.log(window.default); } catch (error) { console.warn("error window.default")}
</script>
```

```
// package.json dependencies

"webpack": "^5.50.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

I am expected to see a function signature at some point but everything is undefined.

I am probably missing something obvious but... I haven't found the answer yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was only for `npx webpack serve` and not `npx webpack`. When building the library with `npx webpack` and serving it with a local static server, the library was loading just fine.

The problem with `npx webpack serve` is a bug within the library webpack-dev-server and is going to be fixed in version 4.0.0 in a few days.